# Bond income calculation question

Tags: bonds, treasury

I thought I got my Bond income right, but my brokerage company's calculator got me totally confused. So here is the problem:
I bought a note (US treasury) yesterday: cusip: 912828TN0 (secondary market)
Coupon rate: 1%
Maturity date: 8/31/19;
Settlement date - 5/1/19;
YTM at a purchase point: 2.409%;
I paid accrued interest: $1.68;
my principle: $995.20;
Can you tell me, please, how much money should I get back on 8/31/19? :)
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: These are sold with a $1000 face value per note. Doesn’t the statement tell you the value at maturity?

Comment: I know the value at maturity. That's not what I am asking about. I'd like to know how much money, in total, I am supposed to get back, including the interest

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you bought one $1,000 note, you will get $1,005 at maturity. The $1,000 principal plus the 0.5% (semi-annual 1%) coupon.

You paid for roughly 2 months of accrued interest (`$5 * 2/6 = 1.67`) when you bought the note, and get the full 6 months when it settles, so your *net* interest will be $3.32.

Your net yield is therefore `(1005/996.88 ^ 12/4) - 1 = 2.46%` The difference between that and your quote is probably due to a more accurate daycount than just the number of months to maturity.

> I bought a note with the Yield to Maturity of 2.409%. Shouldn't I be getting 6 month of this annual rate? and NOT the coupon rate?

No - yield to maturity is your return *relative to what you paid for the note*, and annualized (in your case, the return is 0.8% or about $8 over 4 months). The interest paid is fixed at 1% of the note amount (or 0.5% twice a year).

Comment: I killed my answer. T-bills are semi-annual as you wrote. I’m guessing that’s what OP has.

Comment: You had me doubting myself for a minute :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Here what I am confused about: I bought a note with the Yield to Maturity of 2.409%. Shouldn't I be getting 6 month of this annual rate? and NOT the coupon rate?

Comment: @GemStone See my edit.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  0.8% is my return for 4 months - it is 2.4% annually! :) At the end it aligns.